# B1B2 Visa Stay Query: How long should I stay outside the US after a 10 week stay before which I can come in again?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

So I have stayed in the US for a period of 10 weeks on my B1B2. My purpose is genuine. I was starting my company's base in a particular city and meeting clients and onboarding them. And now, I need to come back to the US after 4 weeks outside the US, but this time for a period of 3 weeks. This is because the clients already onboarded need to have a single round of meetings.

Is this okay? Will they stop me at immigration? Will it affect my visa?

Comment: Also, the 10 week stay was my first stay in the US. And secondly, my future visit frequency will only decrease and not increase.

Comment: @Aishak Dhar The usual advice is to spend at least the same amount of time outside the USA as within it. A 10 week stay does look quite lengthy, especially for a first visit, was the time you spent in the US in accordance with your original plan? I doubt whether the Border agents will place much credence on intangible future visit plans at the point when you want to enter a second time, will you have a confirmed outbound flight for your departure after the intended 3 weeks?

Comment: @Traveller I think the usual advice applies when people are close to the maximum allowed stay, which is not the case here: the combined duration of both visits is half the maximum allowed duration of one visit.

Comment: You need to stay outside the US long enough to get on a new flight. There is no waiting period.